# Spring customization of scheduler

Tags: spring, kotlin, asynchronous, scheduler

I want to implement some custom logic of processing data. It must satisfy two requirements

1. When a new record is being added to database, launch async task/job
   to process it
2. record processing must not be called more than once in
   X seconds.

By implementing (2) I want to avoid spam of another service, but also if there is no other unprocessed records, i want an immediate execution (1).

If i use Spring Scheduled, which allows cron triggers or periodic, it does not satisfy (1) requirement. If i just run a new async task for every request then it does not satisfy (2) requirement

Is there any approach / framework to implement such logic.

Comment: Is this just a thought experiment?  If not, go back to the team that created these requirements and explain to them that this design could never be used in a production environment because, at most, it allows a throughput of 1 record every X seconds.  This doesn't feel like a use case for Spring's scheduler because scheduled jobs run on an interval, not an event.

Comment: no, this is actually not an experiment. we are working with legacy service, which suffers a lot when get called often, thats why i want 1 time per X seconds.

Comment: I would encourage you to solve the performance issues instead of working around them.  Even very complex services can easily handle hundreds or thousands of records per second